# Windows 10で、Atomを既定のプログラムに設定することができない

Tags: windows, windows-10, atom-editor

使用OS:Windows 10

phpファイルをAtomで開くようにしたいと思い、右クリックから「プログラムから開く→別のプログラムを選択→常にこのアプリを使って.phpファイルを開く」でAtomを選択すると、選択したphpファイルがAtomで開かれるのですが、既定のプログラムに設定されず、ファイルのアイコンも何も選択されていない無地(?)の状態です。
選択するAtom.exeを「C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe」にしても、「C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin\atom.cmd」にしても、「C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.32.0\atom.exe」にしてもダメです。
コントロールパネルからアンインストールして、再インストールしてもダメです。
また、phpだけでなく、txtでもcssでもダメです。
VS CodeやBracketsには関連付けられるので、Atomの問題だと思うのですが・・・

どなたか心当たりのある方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？

追記 : Sublime Textも関連付けることができませんでした。

Comment: 問題はアイコンが変更されない事ですか？　.phpファイルを右クリックから「開く」を選択すると、何が起きるのですか？　また、コマンドプロンプトでコマンド "atom" を実行すると何が起きますか？

Comment: 問題はアイコンが変更されないことよりも、Atomを既定のプログラムにできないことです。右クリックで開くとAtomが起動されます。コマンドプロンプトで「Atom」と入力すると、Atomが起動します。一度起動したAtomは正常に動作します。Atomが既定のファイルに設定されることをWindowsが拒絶しているような印象を受けます。

Comment: 勘違いしていました。右クリックで開いてもAtomは起動されません。Atomの前に既定のプログラムに設定していたエディターが起動されます。

Answer (score 1):

関係があるかわかりませんが、共有しておきます。

- [拡張子と既定のアプリケーションの関連付けを変更できない](https://blog.jhashimoto.net/entry/2018/11/09/181105)

（[2018年10月9日にリリースされた Windows アップデート](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462919/windows-10-update-kb4462919)のバグで関連付けに失敗することがあるというものです。2018年11月下旬に解決策が提供される見込みとのことです。）

Answer (score 0):

右クリックから「プログラムから開く」ではなく「開く」でAtomが起動しているのなら、Atomが既定のプログラムに設定されているのだと思います（プログラムを指定せずに「開く」を選択すると、既定のプログラムが起動されます）

アイコンが正しく表示されないのは、アイコンキャッシュが壊れているからではないでしょうか。

[【Win10】 アイコンキャッシュの再構築](https://suu-net.net/archives/598)　のページにアイコンキャッシュの再構築方法が書かれているので、試してみてください。
（セーフモードで再起動して、その後で普通に再起動しても、アイコンキャッシュが再構築されます）

Comment: 勘違いしていました。右クリックで開いてもAtomは起動されません。Atomの前に既定のプログラムに設定していたエディターが起動されます。ダブルクリックするとAtomで開かれるようにしたいのですが・・・

Comment: 質問に書かれている『右クリックから「プログラムから開く→別のプログラムを選択→常にこのアプリを使って.phpファイルを開く」でAtomを選択すると、選択したphpファイルがAtomで開かれる』という動作は起きているのでしょうか？

Comment: ちゃんと起きています。でも既定のプログラムにはなっていないんです。

Comment: 同じ質問の繰り返しになりますが、『.phpファイルを右クリックから「開く」を選択すると、何が起きるのですか？』

Comment: 現在、phpファイルをBracketsに関連付けているので、右クリックから「開く」を選択するとファイルがBracketsで開かれます。右クリックから「プログラムから開く→別のプログラムを選択→常にこのアプリを使って.phpファイルを開く」でAtomを選択すると、選択したphpファイルがAtomで開かれますが、既定のプログラムはBracketsのままです。